# Need to clear data after update or app will not work

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, google-play, google-play-console

After I download my app from the play store and go to Settings -> Apps -> myApp -> Storage, it will have 4.59 mb of data for some reason. Even if i haven't opened the app at all. I have to hit clear data or my app will not run. Once I do clear the data it runs fine, until the next update, then I have to do it again.

Logcat says

```
audit: type=1701 audit(1560151257.983:14744): auid=4294967295 uid=10521 gid=10521 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c9,c258,c512,c768 pid=31263 comm="UnityMain" exe="/system/bin/app_process64" sig=11
```

one time logcat said this instead

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: UnityMain
    Process: com.myord.myapp, PID: 28413
    java.lang.Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 000000000000012f
    Build fingerprint: 'samsung/crownqltesq/crownqltesq:9/PPR1.180610.011/N960USQS1CSD1:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '11'
    pid: 28413, tid: 28431, name: UnityMain  >>> com.myorg.myapp <<<
        x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000000000  x2   0000007b48d66be8  x3   0000000000000000
        x4   0000007b48d66b28  x5   0000000000000004  x6   0000007b59722d80  x7   00000000013e61f7
        x8   0000000000000001  x9   7a0a23fc6ec12b11  x10  0000007b44beb000  x11  0000007b4552407c
        x12  00000000000005e7  x13  0000000000000001  x14  0000000000000008  x15  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
        x16  0000007b464635e0  x17  0000007be651da20  x18  0000000000000001  x19  0000007b46510000
        x20  0000000000000000  x21  0000000000000000  x22  0000007b4675dab8  x23  0000007b46514000
        x24  0000007b45fc35d8  x25  0000007b467402d8  x26  0000007b46020104  x27  0000007b45fbeef7
        x28  0000007b48d67430  x29  0000007b48d66c50  x30  0000007b45841454
        sp   0000007b48d66c20  pc   0000007b45841468  pstate 0000000060000000

        at [vdso].(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.(:0)
        at libil2cpp.il2cpp_init(il2cpp_init:44)
        at libunity.(:0)
        at libunity.(:0)
        at libunity.(:0)
        at libunity.(:0)
        at base.(:0)
```

i also see this alot at the end

```
Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: Check this out https://forum.unity.com/threads/crash-error-fatal-exception.248015/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in manifest.

```
android:fullBackupContent="false"
```

This worked for me!!!

Comment: Now you dont need to clear data everytime you update

Comment: Okay really excited to try this. But uh, how do i do that? Ive developed in Android Studio before. Would I have to export the project into android studio then do it there? Or is there some way to do it in unity? I've googled this before but all the questions i came across pointed to a manifest folder in unity that i could never find. Thanks!

Comment: See, I am no unity developer. But i did some digging and found this. Hope this will be helpful. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-manifest.html

Comment: Okay I will check this out, thanks again. But just to be clear. This fixed your problem Even if it wasnt an update correct? Like if you completely un installed the program and reinstalled it your app would crash instantly, and this would fix it?

Comment: Yes, buddy. I faced this problem many times. Every time it used to crash until I do clear data and cache. Once I came up with solution. Voila it was fixed in my scenario.

Comment: That was it! Ah thank you so much! After all this work i thought i was ready for release, it was so frustrating! Sounds like you know my pain!

Comment: It just basically tells the system to clear everything when updates the app